# Python.Форматирование полученной строки

Tags: python, sqlite, format

я глупый.
Учусь работать с SQLITE, получаю из таблицы количество монеток по id вот таким образом:
`id = 399364630
sql = "SELECT coins FROM persons WHERE id=?"
cur.execute(sql, [(id)])
print(cur.fetchone())`

В ответ приходит вот такая анимешка `(3,)`  Число то верное, цифра 3, но как превратить её просто в `3` без скобочек, или может вообще надо по другому обращаться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как в извлечённой из базы строке может быть больше одного поля, метод `fetchone` возвращает вам *кортеж* значений. Извлечь первый элемент кортежа можно по индексу:

```
print(cur.fetchone()[0])
```

или с помощью *распаковки*

```
print(*cur.fetchone())
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @WestSide [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).